# Record from all 3 microphones in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

From what I understand the iPhone5 has 3 separate microphones (see [here](http://www.finalpointlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/iPhone-Mic.jpg)), is it possible to record audio from all 3 mics simultaneously? I've been digging through the documents, and I've started digging into RemoteIO and CoreAudio but I can't figure out if its even possible to specify which built-in microphone to record from? Does anyone have any experience with this, or know if its even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I'm onto a solution, I found this article in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1799/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013720

Comment: Hi Mike, can you accept an answer to your question so that I can have a duplicate question point to this one? (I didn't notice your comment before posting my own answer. Feel free to post your own answer and mark it correct if you want.)

Comment: It looks to me as though you have accepted an answer that does not in fact answer the question.

Comment: Nah, it's the best possible answer. I think this is the API to let you do it, but sadly it's not possible to record from multiple sources and AVAudioSession is a singleton so can't get multiple instances of it. So, there is no answer right now. If I figure this out, I'll update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Is it possible to record from multiple microphones at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420918/ios-is-it-possible-to-record-from-multiple-microphones-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Pi's comment below is probably correct: You can select which mic to record from, but can't record from multiple mics at same time.

[Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1799/_index.html) it's possible since iOS 7:

> Using APIs introduced in iOS 7, developers can perform tasks such as
>   locating a port description that represents the built-in microphone,
>   locating specific microphones like the "front", "back" or "bottom",
>   setting your choice of microphone as the preferred data source,
>   setting the built-in microphone port as the preferred input and even
>   selecting a preferred microphone polar pattern if the hardware
>   supports it. See AVAudioSession.h.

Comment: I don't see any suggestion in that text/link that it is possible to consume data from multiple microphone simultaneously. Sure, you can choose one of the available microphones from which to record.